# How to use TimeDistributed Layer with Convolutional layer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a very basic self-driving car steering angle prediction problem. I have around a video taken at 30fps and I've converted it into images of around 50000(i.e roughly 25 mins of footage) and I'm trying to predict target which is steering angle.

I have tried to use few basic convolutional layers but the MSE that I've got is very bad. So, I'm trying to use CNN + RNN to improve my model. As it make sense to use RNN's because my data is time distributed.

I don't know how to use `TimeDistributed Layer` along with `LSTM` for this. I'm basically using something like this below, I have each image of shape `width, height, channel = (200, 66, 3)`

```
img_height = 66
img_width = 200
channels = 3

input_l = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, channels))
x = layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(5, 5))(input_l)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5, 5))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs=input_l, outputs=out)
model.summary()
```

As far I've learned that TimeDistributedLayer takes 4 dimensions in order to work but my each image is of shape (200, 66, 3) and how can I convert my each image into four dimension. I can't figure out on how exactly to use this. I've read through few articles but none of them talked about this.

How do I incorporate Time-distributed Layer along with LSTM into this architecture? Can anyone provide a sample code on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

The TimeDistributed layer assumes that dimension 1 is the time dimension (timesteps), so you need to add a time dimension to your image data.  Something like:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models

time_steps = 10
img_height = 66
img_width = 200
channels = 3

input_l = layers.Input(shape=(time_steps, img_height, img_width, channels))
x = layers.TimeDistributed( layers.Conv2D( 32, kernel_size=(5, 5) ) ) (input_l)
x = layers.TimeDistributed( layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(5, 5)) ) (x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
out = layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = models.Model(inputs=input_l, outputs=out)
model.summary()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: but my input is images and there are of 3 dimension right? each image is (width, height, channels). How can I pass it it when it expects 4 dimensional input. All my train images are in train folder and test images are in test folder. Can you provide some code on how to process data into this model?

Comment: if I understand your processing, you started with videos which you converted to images. Depending on how you plan to create your model, you need to pack some of the image frames into a 4 dimensional array.  For example, you could create 5 seconds worth of data (5*30 fps) which would give you 150 time steps/frames, each time step having a 3D image and that 150 frame sequence would be treated as one "sample" by the network.  The LSTM would then make a prediction based on the 150 time steps.  I hope that makes sense and helps.

Comment: So that would mean my each sample in a batch will be of shape (5(images), width, height, channel) right. And If I consider a batch size of 32 then the size of one batch will be (32, 5, width, height, channel) that would mean each sample consists of 5 images. Am I correct here?

Comment: And here I"m doing a regression problem so my y-target for one batch wsill be of shape (32, 5) isn't it? But here I'm receiving a error `ValueError: A target array with shape (160, 5) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.`

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can provide an example with a dummy example dataset. So I can check the sizes of input. I can't seem to figure out exact shapes of input for target.